# How to check if ObjectIdentifier is root of another ObjectIdentifier? (SnmpSharpNet)

Tags: c#, snmp, snmpsharpnet

How would I check if an `ObjectIdentifier` is parent/root of another `ObjectIdentifier`?

For example:

```
ObjectIdentifier rootId = ...;
Variable variable = ...;
if (rootId.IsRootOf(variable.Id))
{
    // The variable's id is a child of root id!
}
```

I can't seem to find any method like that in [SnmpSharpNet](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/).

Comment: Convert to strings and then use `.StartsWith`.

Answer (score 0):

rootId is a parent if this is true

is-equal (rootId, variableId, len(rootId))

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? I am not sure what you mean. How would I implement this IsEqual method?

Comment: Your API must have a comparison operation on OID type for a certain length. Since OIDs are hierarchical, if they are the same upto the length of the smaller of the 2, then by definition the smaller of the 2 is the parent of the longer.